# Mutual information between input training image and difference between two logits

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I’m trying to replicate the experiment made by Rafael Muller et al. in “[When does label smoothing help?](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8717-when-does-label-smoothing-help.pdf)” NIPS, 2019

The method is mainly descibed in section 4 and figure 6 for evaluating the effect of label smoothing in network distillation with classification tasks:
"We measure the mutual information between X and Y , where X is a discrete variable representing the index of the training example and Y is continuous representing the difference between two logits (out of K classes). The exact formula used for mutual information approximation is written in page 7.

I’m trying to replicate this experiment using ResNet18 on Cifar-10 dataset.

After each epoch, I run this piece of code to compute the mutual information as described in the paper. However, the computed mutual information final value is totally far away from its feasible range from 0 to log(N):
batchsize = 300, N = 600 (no. of training instances used in Mutual Inf. calculation), L = 100 (MonteCarlo samples), and classes_mi is a 1-d array containing indices of two classes which we are using during Mutual inf. calculation

```
with torch.no_grad():
    #Mean calculation
    for i in range(self.L):
        for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(trainloader_sub_transforms[i]):
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)
            outputs = (self.net(inputs)).cpu().detach().numpy()
            outputs = np.absolute(outputs[:, classes_mi[0]] - outputs[:, classes_mi[1]])
            mu_x[batch_idx*300:batch_idx*300 + len(targets)] += outputs
    mu_x /= self.L
    print('--> Finish Mean Calculation ', mu_x[:10])
    #STD Calculation
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(trainloader_sub):
        inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)
        outputs = (self.net(inputs)).cpu().detach().numpy()
        outputs = np.absolute(outputs[:, classes_mi[0]] - outputs[:, classes_mi[1]])
        var = np.sum((outputs - mu_x[batch_idx*300:batch_idx*300 + len(targets)]) ** 2)
    var /= self.N
    print('--> Finish VAR Calculation ', var)
    #Mutual Information Calculation
    mutual_info_value = np.zeros(self.N)
    term2 = 0
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(trainloader_sub):
        print('batch_idx2 = ', batch_idx)
        inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)
        outputs = (self.net(inputs)).cpu().detach().numpy()
        outputs = np.absolute(outputs[:, classes_mi[0]] - outputs[:, classes_mi[1]])
        main_term = -(outputs - mu_x[batch_idx*300:batch_idx*300+len(targets)])**2 / (2 * var)
        term2  +=  np.sum(np.exp( main_term ))
        mutual_info_value[batch_idx*300:batch_idx*300 + len(targets)] = main_term
    term2 = np.log(term2)
    mutual_info_value -= term2
    print(mutual_info_value.shape, mutual_info_value[:10])
    mutual_info_value = np.sum(mutual_info_value)
sum += mutual_info_value
print('trial: ', t, ' --> MI = ', mutual_info_value)
```

Comment: Could you provide some of the output that you are calculating?

Comment: Mean values = [4.567, 1.846, 2.27, ....] (N values)
Variance = 1.063
mutual_info_value = -3974 (it should be from 0 to log(N),  term2 = 6.0579

Comment: I actually doubt that the formula written in the paper is totally correct one but have no idea how do they end up with this approximation formula exactly.